# Lion seems to have made both Safari and Chrome pause when opening more tabs

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browsing

I recently upgraded to Lion and am mostly very pleased. However I'm having some errant behaviour when CMD clicking on links in Safari and Chrome. Instead of opening the page in a new tab, often nothing happens until I do the same again, at which point two tabs open to the target page.
This doesn't happen every time, but now it's happening more often than not.

I'm using a late 2008 Unibody MacBook with the glass trackpad.

Since both Safari and Chrome pause when opening more tabs, I'm a bit at a loss where to look next for a cause or solution.

Comment: How many tabs do you have open on the browsers. I've noticed Chrome get very slow to respond to new tabs after around 35 open tabs.

Comment: I haven't experienced that with Lion, but I'm curious to know if you see any messages from Safari in Console.app when this happens.

Comment: Jamie - Welcome! - I'm going to edit this a bit as the custom here is to not sign in the body of the question. Please do edit in one or two examples of a website with a link that is causing this - often it's related to how the link is telling Safari where to open the new link (like in another window or other target)

Comment: Hi! @bmike Thanks for the edit and advice :)

@Randolph West, this happened with only 2 or 3 tabs open at any one time.

@bneely, this is something that I should have thought of, thanks! I did it and the following message (or variations thereof) appeared every time:

`22.08.2011 10:34:43.812 sandboxd: ([52241]) WebProcess(52241) deny file-read-data /Users/jamie/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AIR/ELS/BBCiPlayerDesktop.61DB7A798358575D6A969CCD73DDBBD723A6DA9D.1/APSPrivateData/052B00379E6AE54ADE7AF005E8D5059Ck.dat`

I uninstalled Adobe Air and so far it seems ok, I'll repost if it reappears!

Comment: Awesome! Go ahead add this as an answer to your question. Some of the best questions were asked, solved and answered by the same person - just like yours. You can come back and edit the answer if you find something else out later ...